# Combobox text is giving fake info

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, mahapps.metro

I added a new ComboBox for theme changing. And when i select item it works good, selection is changed, but when i get Text from that ComboBox it returns another item text in ComboBox. I dont know what is problem, i noticed this by adding debug TextBox and printing inside Text from ComboBox on event when i change selection.

Here is code:

```
private void Themecb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (themeedit == 1)
            {
                String txt = Themecb.Text;
                TextBox1.Text = "THEME WORK " + txt;
                Tuple<AppTheme, Accent> appStyle = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
                ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                                            ThemeManager.GetAccent(txt),
                                            ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseLight")); // or appStyle.Item1
            }
        }
```

And here is XML file:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Themecb" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="237,227,0,0" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="120" 
SelectionChanged="Themecb_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Comment: Did you try to get the value by SelectedItem property? Try to replace the line `String txt = Themecb.Text;` with `String txt = Themecb.SelectedItem as string;` please and let me know if it returns wrong value too.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me!

Comment: Glad to know it helped! I`ll post this comment as an answer, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to get the value by SelectedItem property? Try to replace the line `String txt = Themecb.Text;` with `String txt = Themecb.SelectedItem as string;`

Answer (score 0):

replace `Themecb.Text` with `Themecb.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox has two main propeties
SelectedText and SelectedValue

SelectedText is the string text of the selected item
SelectedValue is the value that use to identify each item in backend

so in your case try as bellow

```
if (themeedit == 1)
            {
                String txt = Themecb.SelectedText;
                TextBox1.Text = "THEME WORK " + txt;
                Tuple<AppTheme, Accent> appStyle = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
                ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                                            ThemeManager.GetAccent(txt),
                                            ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseLight")); // or appStyle.Item1
            }
```